# javascript regular expression cases

Tags: javascript, regex

This script below

```
 jQuery(".lireArticleAction a").each(function(){
                jQuery(this).attr('href',jQuery(this).attr('href').replace(/\/\/(\d)_.(\d{3})\//,'/'));
        })
```

works for :

```
<span class="lireArticleAction" id="lireArticle">
<a href="website/abc/d/e/1_.000/DispForm.aspx?ID=1" class="">read</a>
        </span>
```

returns : http://website/abc/d/e/DispForm.aspx?ID=1

but not for :

```
<span class="lireArticleAction" id="lireArticle">
<a href="website/abc/d/e/10_.000/DispForm.aspx?ID=10" class="">read</a>
        </span>
```

which returns: http://website/abc/d/e/10_.000/DispForm.aspx?ID=10

how can i make it work for 1_.000, 10_.000, 100_.000, 1000_.000, etc...?

here is a test on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/atoswchataigner/5uh8N/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a plus sign after `\/\/\d`. `\/\/\d+` means: "match all consecutive digits after `//`:

```
/\/\/(\d+)_.(\d{3})\//
```

Instead of your current RegExp, you can also use:

```
jQuery(this).attr('href',jQuery(this).prop('href').replace(/(?!:)\/\//g,'/'));
```

The `.prop` method returns a parsed URL, rather than the set attribute. The `/(?:)\/\//g` regular expression replaces all occurences of double slash by a single slash, except for slashses which are preceded by a `:` (which postfixes a protocol: `http://`).

Answer (score 1):

`/\/\/(\d+)_.(\d{3})\//,'/'`

The `+` will match one or more digits.

Comment: same answer proposed earlier :)